# Toast notification using JavaScript + CSS not working properly on login page (node.js + express + passport + MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, mongodb

I've been working on a project as part of a JavaScript course and I've decided to try something new. The project itself was to build a simple page where the user could register or delete cars, which would appear on a list

Well, it worked out fine after some struggle. So what I decided to do was to implement a login page, using express, passport, and MongoDB (and mongoose to connect MongoDB).

It also worked out.

I am using a Toast notification when the user adds/removes a car (as taught here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkuZTAMyAFI).

Inside the carshop.html page, it works just fine. Here is the Toast.js:

```
const Toast = {
    init() {
        this.hideTimeout = null;

        this.el = document.createElement('div');
        this.el.className = 'toastNotification';
        document.body.appendChild(this.el);
    },

    show(message, state) {
        clearTimeout(this.hideTimeout);

        this.el.textContent = message;
        this.el.className = 'toastNotification toastNotification--visible';

        if (state) {
            this.el.classList.add(`toastNotification--${state}`);
        }

        this.hideTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.el.classList.remove('toastNotification--visible')
        }, 2000);
    }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => Toast.init());

export default Toast;
```

and the Toast css:

```
.toastNotification {
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: fixed;
    right: 10%;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    
    padding: 1.2em;
    background: #00afb9;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #fdfcdc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fed9b7;

    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, top 0.5s, visibility 0.5s;
}

.toastNotification--visible {
    top: 2%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.toastNotification--excluded {
    background: #f07167;
    color: #fdfcdc;

}

.toastNotification--added {
    background: #00afb9;
    color: #fdfcdc;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .toastNotification {
        padding: 0.6em;
        font-size: 0.6em;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fed9b7;
    }
}
```

When the user add/removes a car, Toast.show is called like that:

```
Toast.show('Carro adicionado com sucesso!', 'added'); //added
Toast.show('Carro excluído com sucesso.', 'excluded'); //deleted
```

**The problem:**

I tried to reuse this scheme on the login page when the user passes the wrong email/password. This is handled by the server like that:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local',
        (err, user, info) => {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            if (!user) {
                return res.redirect('/login?info=' + info);
            }

            req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }

                return res.redirect('/carshop');
            });

        })(req, res, next);
});
```

Following the tutorial to set the login page, it was instructed to create the following script to handle login errors:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const info = urlParams.get('info');

if (info) {
   // action when there's an error with login info
}
```

If I import Toast and try to run Toast.show(par1, par2) inside the block, there's an error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of undefined

I managed to overcome that by initializing Toast again inside the block:

```
if (info) {
    Toast.init();
    Toast.show('Dados incorretos', 'excluded');
}
```

Now it kinda works... but the animations won't - the whole idea with Toast. An error notification appears, but it just stays there:

[image: printscreen of error]

So I have two questions:

1 - why is it not working when I just call Toast.show(), without calling Toast.init() again inside the block - although when the login page loads, a toast div is created inside body's HTML?
2 - why are the animations not working when I call Toast.init() again?

***EDIT:***

so here is the login.js so far:

```
import Toast from "./toast/toast.js";

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const info = urlParams.get('info');

if (info) {
    Toast.init();
    Toast.show('Dados incorretos', 'excluded');
}
```

***EDIT... AGAIN. AND A SOLUTION!***

Thanks to Neuchter's answer, I made it work:

> Then maybe your problem goes away when you don't rely on this that heavily and instead target the element directly by giving it and id querying that in calls to show

There were two problems: first, using `this` was not working after reloading the page when submitting the form with the wrong user/password. second, the new page, after reloading, was not calling `Toast.init()`, so there was no div to be accessed by `Toast.show()`.

My solution was to hardcode the Toast div in the html:

```
<div class="toastNotification" id="toast"></div>
```

And to change toast.js to get rid of `this` in `Toast.show()`:

```
const Toast = {
    init() {
        this.hideTimeout = null;

        this.el = document.createElement('div');
        this.el.className = 'toastNotification';
        this.el.id = 'toast';
        document.body.appendChild(this.el);
    },

    show(message, state) {
        clearTimeout(this.hideTimeout);

        const $toast = document.querySelector('#toast');

        $toast.textContent = message;
        $toast.className = 'toastNotification toastNotification--visible';

        if (state) {
            $toast.classList.add(`toastNotification--${state}`);
        }

        this.hideTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            $toast.classList.remove('toastNotification--visible')
        }, 2000);
    }
};
```

Now, when Toast.show() on the login page, it works just fine:

```
import Toast from "./toast/toast.js";

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const info = urlParams.get('info');

if (info) {
    Toast.show('Dados incorretos', 'excluded');
}
```

Comment: How are you importing the toast into the login page? Not being able to set the `textContent` and it being "fixed" when manually running `init` indicates to me that the `DOMContentLoaded` event has already passed at that point...

Comment: here: import Toast from "./toast/toast.js";

Comment: I'm not going to look thru the entire repo. It's good stackoverflow etiquette and greatly increases your chances of getting a useful answer when you can narrow down your issue so far that you can provide a minimal reproducible example in code.

Comment: without manually running Toast.init(), when the login page loads, this div is added to the html - as it happens inside the carshop page => <div class="toastNotification"></div>

Comment: Then maybe your problem goes away when you don't rely on `this` that heavily and instead target the element directly by giving it and id an querying that in calls to `show`

Comment: Thank you. I targeted the element directly, and it actually worked. The other problem, I realized, is that when I submit the form with the wrong data, it reloads the page - obviously -, and this new page doesn't load Toast.init(). I don't know why Toast.init() is not called again, but it worked nevertheless using Toast.init() manually.